# Visa for connecting flights at Kuala Lumpur, different airlines?

Tags: visas, singapore, malaysia

I am an Indian citizen travelling to Singapore via Kuala Lumpur.

I have 2 flights (different air lines) from same terminal with layover of 5 hours in Kuala Lumpur. Not planning to go out of airport but as its different flights would need to collect luggage and go through immigration I guess.

New Delhi -> Kuala Lumpur (KLIA2) (Air Asia flight arrives 7.05 am)

Kuala Lumpur (KLIA2) -> Singapore (Jetstar flight departs 11.15 am)

Do I need any visa? Is it the transit visa which is required? How can I get the transit visa?